# Internal Forced Convection of Water/Air

Tags: heat-transfer

Should I take the film mean temperature or bulk mean temperature to obtain the water/air properties from the Steam Tables? (In order to calculate Re number - for Petukhov's empirical relation calculation)

e.g. A smooth pipe with a diameter of 2.0cm is maintained at a constant wall temperature of 90degC. Water enters the rube at 40 degC and leaves at 60 degC. If the entering velocity is 3 m/s, calculate the length of tube necessary to accomplish the heating.

Comment: Check out the values at 60, 75 and 90… how much difference do you get in Re? How much effect on the friction factor?

Comment: steam tables are for liquid/vapor mixtures of water.  Air means oxygen and nitrogen.  WAter at 40- 60 C will have a negligible vapor component.